# Is necessary to use imap_close?

Tags: php, ajax, imap

I usually use php IMAP functions but do not close the IMAP stream. Is necessary and what are the benefits?

I have an intranet panel that reads my email account. An ajax call gets the email from a PHP script which opens the IMAP connection. But I call that PHP with ajax a lot, around once every 2 seconds for around 30 seconds. I open a new connection every time, but do not close it.

Sometimes I get an strange lag, when using this file. Could keeping the IMAP connection open cause the issue?

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy to test? Put in imap_close and see if your issue goes away.

Comment: Yes of course but I wanted to know if is necessary to close or not.  Since I didn't find information about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imap_close() is not required as connection will be closed regardless when your script finishes. However having open connection keeps imapd child on the server and they are not light. Having imap_close() straight after you have finished with it having benefit of freeing up resources on imap server if your script continues to run after you have finished working with imap. Calling imap_close() just before end of the script technically not needed as connection will be closed anyway but it should be done just of being nice to imap server :)

Also if your script opens connections in quick succession then you should re-think your design: imap_open() is very expensive function in terms of resources on imap server.

Comment: Can I somehow keep the conection open even if I call the php with ajax?

Comment: Make your ajax connection persistent and keep your php script running indefinitely until ajax connection is dropped. This way you only need to open imap connection on php script start and would not hog resources on imap server.

Comment: You mean call the php just 1 time ? But javascript freezes the browser until the ajax finishes.  If the ajax takes 15 seconds it would freeze the page for 15 secs.

Comment: Ah?! Do you know what first 'A' stands in AJAX? Asynchronous. AJAX is asynchronous by definition and if your javascript stops processing AJAX requests something is really broken on browser side. Quite likely you have thrown alot of javascript together in one thread while you actually should have AJAX calls to imap separately so it would not hold up the rest of java scripts. I strongly suggest you to look at your ajax design and make ajax-php-imap connector as separate function.

Comment: Thank you I will review that